# Javascript drawing an elastic rectangle band

Tags: javascript, canvas, xor

I am trying to create a drag rectangle in Javascript, which allows a user to draw a rectangle by dragging for the purpose of selecting a region on the canvas.

I am trying to use "xor" operation to do the repeated drawing on mouse move handler.  But I am unable to get this right.

My code is a single html file, as shown below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        /*body, html {
            width: 100%
        }*/
        #canvas {
            background-color: #EFEFEF;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas">
        canvas
    </canvas>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;

        var canvasOffset, offsetX, offsetY;
        var isDrawing = false;
        var prevX, prevY;
        canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
        offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
        offsetY = canvasOffset.top;

        $("#canvas").on('mousedown', function(e) {
            handleMouseDown(e);
        }).on('mouseup', function(e) {
            handleMouseUp();
        }).on('mousemove', function(e) {
            handleMouseMove(e);
        });

        function handleMouseUp() {
            isDrawing = false;
            canvas.style.cursor = "default";
        }

        function handleMouseMove(e) {
            if (isDrawing) {
                var mouseX = e.clientX - offsetX;
                var mouseY = e.clientY - offsetY;
                ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "xor";
                ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
                ctx.beginPath();
                console.log("Erasing rect @ ", start_X, start_Y, prevX - start_X, prevY - start_Y);
                ctx.rect(start_X, start_Y, prevX - start_X, prevY - start_Y);

                console.log("Drawing rect @ ", start_X, start_Y, mouseX - start_X, mouseY - start_Y);
                ctx.rect(start_X, start_Y, mouseX - start_X, mouseY - start_Y);
                prevX = mouseX, prevY = mouseY;
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }

        function handleMouseDown(e) {
            canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
            isDrawing = true;
            start_X = e.clientX - offsetX;
            start_Y = e.clientY - offsetY;
            prevX = start_X, prevY = start_Y;
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the jsfiddle link for my code. http://jsfiddle.net/bjc7bp0q/1/

The problems are:
i) It doesn't start drawing from the point where mouse was clicked.
ii) It doesn't erase previous rectangle strokes.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**Update**
As suggested by Derek, updated the jsfiddle, with corrections for canvas stretch due to width:100%, and pixel offset by 0.5 for blur compensation.

updated jsfiddle is here (http://jsfiddle.net/bjc7bp0q/8/).  This *almost* works. But I can still see some stray residual line fragments when dragging.

Thanks for any additional help.

**Second update:**
This seems to work well in Google chrome, but NOT in IE or Firefox.  May be its an implementation issue of these browsers.

Comment: The problem is that you used `width: 100%` in CSS. This will cause the canvas to be stretched. Use the `width` attribute instead of the `width` property will solve your first problem.

Comment: Thanx, it solved problem #1.  However xor is not happening.

Comment: Here is a fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bjc7bp0q/4/ Didn't really know the "xor" part you were mentioned, however I believe you would have to erase the canvase with `clearRect`.

Comment: Thanx for the quick fix.  If I were to apply clearRect, it might erase any background drawing the canvas may have.Any reason y xor wouldn't work?

Comment: Wouldn't `xor` also erase your background drawing? I believe `xor` and other composite types are for drawing shapes over the existing pixels (like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html)) instead of animation like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bjc7bp0q/5/).

Comment: OK, u gave an extra offset of 0.5 in the call to ctx.rect. Y is this necessary?

Comment: Without the offset, lines would be blurry because you are drawing right between two pixels. Take a look at [this page](http://www.mobtowers.com/html5-canvas-crisp-lines-every-time/), it explained it well.

Comment: Sounds like you want 'destination-out' rather than 'xor'. Xor will display new pixels if they don't overlap existing pixels. Destination-out will 'erase' both the new & existing pixels.